# Trying to get Root Privileges for Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: root, privileges

I'm trying to run GParted, but it says that I need root privileges. How do I get them for Ubuntu 15.10?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type `pkexec gparted`

Answer (score 0):

try 
`sudo gparted`

or

`sudo su`

`gparted`

Comment: This adds nothing new.

Answer (score -1):

if not installed

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

And to run it

```
sudo gparted > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Extra commands to stop debug messages and send it to background Enter your password and your good to go.